# Enabling/disabling CCButtons in an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a puzzle game with 20 levels using Cocos2D. When a player first opens the game, all the levels should be locked except for level 1. When the player passes level 1, then level 2 button should be enabled and so on...

I put the CCButtons in an array so that I could disable unlocked level buttons in a for loop (rather than each individually), but enabling/disabling the object references from the array doesn't work...

For example, this works: `_level19.enabled = false;`

But this doesn't work: `levels[19].enabled = false;`

Here is the relevant code block after I initialized `CCButton* _level1` to `CCButton* _level20`.

```
-(void) didLoadFromCCB {

    // Only set level buttons as enabled if player has unlocked that level

    CCButton* levels[20] = {_level1, _level2, _level3, _level4, _level5, _level6, _level7, _level8, _level9,
    _level11, _level12, _level13, _level14, _level15, _level16, _level17, _level18, _level19, _level20};

    // CCButtons are automatically enabled so disable all buttons that haven't been unlocked

    for (NSInteger j = [GameState sharedInstance].levelsUnlocked; j > 20; j++) {
        levels[j].enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error or it just doesn't disable the buttons?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Previously it didn't disable the buttons. I'll be more clear with my wording next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

j > 20 seems like a typo. You want to get inside the loop only if your j value is greater than 20 , and then fetch a value from levels array of count 20 which would throw an out of bounds exception.

I am guessing, this should work for you

```
 for (NSInteger j = [GameState sharedInstance].levelsUnlocked; j < 20; j++) {
    levels[j].enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're right. I was so convinced last night that it was a problem with the array reference because my array of buttons also weren't being disabled in another class when a pop-up was opened that I became blind to the typo. I'm so glad it works now. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @blanksblanks glad that i could help :)